# Is there some way where I can set a conditional statement for the values of selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have these order status of 'confirmed','on the way' and 'delivered'. How can I set the value for these status to match the values that I  have in the select options?

- Confirmed - 10
- On the way - 20
- Delivered - 30

In this scenario, if the status was "On the way" then the previous status will be disabled. So I thought, maybe I could set the status of confirmed to 10 and such..

> ```
>   const Orders = () => {
>       const [status, setStatus] = useState("");
>       const [value, setValue] = useState();
>       const handleChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);
>       return (
>         <div>
>               <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
>                 <FormControl>
>                
>                   <Select onChange={handleChange} value={value}>
>                     <MenuItem value={10} disabled={value > 10}>
>                       Confirmed
>                     </MenuItem>
>                     <MenuItem value={20} disabled={value > 20}>
>                       On the way
>                     </MenuItem>
>                     <MenuItem value={30} disabled={value > 30}>
>                       On the way (Delayed)
>                     </MenuItem>
>                     <MenuItem value={40} disabled={value > 40}>
>                       Delivered
>                     </MenuItem>
>                   </Select>
>                 </FormControl>
>                 <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
>               </form>
>         </div>
>       );
>     };
> ```

Comment: Can you clarify what "set the value for these status" means? Your question is rather unclear (to me).

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: I copy/pasted this code into a codesandbox and it *seems* to work... do you want *all* previous options disabled, or only the option "below" disabled, i.e. if `value == 30` then ***only*** option value `20` is disabled?

Comment: yes it does work, however, I'm getting the status from an API. How will the select option know if the status value is 10,20, 30, or 40?

Comment: So you want that when `status` state updates that the `value` state updates to match?

Comment: yes, something like that. Like if my status if 'On the way' then the previous status won't be selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232625/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-jen-jennie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand of your question you want to limit the available options of the `Select` component based on a dynamic `status` value.

You can instead disable the options based on the status value. For this you will need to "map" a status to a value that easily matches the option values used by the `Select`. For simplicity we'll use your 10, 20, 30, and 40 values.

```
const statusMap = {
  Confirmed: 10,
  "On the way": 20,
  "On the way (Delayed)": 30,
  Delivered: 40,
};
```

Orders - consumes a `status` prop and uses that for the `disabled` attribute for options.

```
const Orders = ({ status }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setValue(0);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormControl>
          <Select onChange={handleChange} value={value}>
            <MenuItem value={10} disabled={status > 10}>
              Confirmed
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20} disabled={status > 20}>
              On the way
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30} disabled={status > 30}>
              On the way (Delayed)
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={40} disabled={status > 40}>
              Delivered
            </MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Usage

```
<Orders status={statusMap[statusValueFromAPI]} />
```

[image: Edit is-there-some-way-where-i-can-set-a-conditional-statement-for-the-values-of-sele]